# Is it possible to infer the class name of the object that a pointer points to in gdb?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

Say if I have this *basePointer* pointers points to a Base class object.

```
(gdb) ptype basePointer
type = class Base {
  public:
    Base(void);
    virtual ~Base(void);
    virtual void hello();
} *
(gdb) p basePointer
$1 = (Base *) 0x100104c00
```

If I know this *0x100104c00*, is it possible to infer the class name of the object that *basePointer* points to in gdb?

Comment: you can get this info by telling gdb to load your symbols

Comment: by using this `add-shared-symbol-files` command in gdb?

Answer (score 0):

try `p (Derived *)basePointer` casting works in gdb as it works in C